# Font Awesome 5 Icons showing up as square in Flask app

Tags: html, flask, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I want to use Font Awesome 5 in my flask application, but the templates just show empty squares or other icons then i wanted them to be/not showing anything.

I downloaded fontawesome5 and put it in the static folder. With

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href="{{ url_for('static', filename='font-awesome5/css/fontawesome.min.css')}}">
```

i link to the css-file.

When using

```
<i class="fab fa-bell"></i>
```

webapp shows:

[image: empty square]

It doesnt matter if i use fa or fab or fas.

There were no problems with Font Awesome 4.

What am i missing?

Edit:
[image: import]

Font-weight 400, 600 and 900 is not working.

I can access the font-awesome.min.css and there is a fa-bell with code f0f3, so import should be okey?
Do I have to set the font-family somewhere in my flask app?

Comment: You may need to set the `font-weight` for them (I believe `font-weight: 400;` is the trick)

Comment: I set the font-weight now, but its still a square.

Comment: Did you try `font-weight: 600;` too? I solved this a long time ago in one my projects with the font-weight, but be 100% sure there is nothing else overriding it. If it's not that or `font-size` for some reason, then it's most likely an importing issue

Comment: for me I use the `"all.min.css"` file and class `"far fa-bell"` for regular and `"fas fa-bell"` for solid

Comment: 'all.min.css' and 'far' unfortunately also not working for me

Comment: make sure your `"webfonts"` that was packaged in the `"fontAwesome"` folder is in the parent directory of the css directory that contains your `"all.min.css"` file, for example `yourProject/css/all.min.css` `yourProject/webfonts`

Comment: so you said you are using Flask, so I assume you have put the file `"all.min.css"` in the css folder in the static directory, also you need to put the `webfonts` folder inside the static directory

Comment: The webfonts folder was missing in my static directory. Thank you all for your ideas and effort :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I found was to use the JavaScript of FontAwesome in the header and then use the "fas fa-*" class.

You can download the files I used from the oficial page:
https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself

**Code that I put in the header:**

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='your_route/fontawesome/js/fontawesome.js')}}"></script>

<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='your_route/fontawesome/js/solid.js')}}"></script
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have font awesome paid KIT? Because bell is pro icon.

https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery As you can check on this link.

Basic Use:
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use

Also your code should be:

```
<i class="fab fa-bell"></i>
```

Not:

```
<i>class="fab fa-bell"></i>
```

Comment: [link](https://fontawesome.com/icons/bell?style=solid) Bell icon in solid style is free to use if i dont understand that wrong?

And sry for the <i>, edited it, but doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

`fab` is used for brand icons. You should replace it with `fas` - solid icons

```
<i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
```